# There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first. C#

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql

When I start debugging that error shows, and it associted with the line:

`textBox1.Text = cmd.ExecuteReader().ToString();`

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"server= M_SHAWAF\ORCHESTRATE; integrated security=true; database=MyData"); 

    try
    {
        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd = new SqlCommand(@"select MAX(Nodelevel) from Org", conn);
        int s = Int32.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        for (int i = 0; i <= s; i++)
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand(@"select Name from Org where NodeLevel=" + i.ToString(),conn);
            textBox1.Text = cmd.ExecuteReader().ToString();
        }

    }


    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }

}
```

How can I fix that??

Comment: Why do you execute your reader in a for loop? At the end, your `textBox1.Text` will be just assigned to last result of the `cmd.ExecuteReader()` when `i` equals to `s`. **BUT WHAT?** Why do you try to do assign your `cmd.ExecuteReader().ToString()` to textbox? That doesn't make sense. And probably `ExecuteReader().ToString();` will return it's full class name instead of data inside of it. And You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). You are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack

Comment: A long story :D
textbox is just a test.

for loop: I'll use it to execute nodes and their child from a hierarchical table

Comment: And use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to dispose your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to continually execute readers in order to obtain the next row of data. If all you need to do is to iterate through all row values of `Name` from table `Org`, you can execute a single Sql query to return all rows into the reader, and then to traverse the reader, e.g.:

```
    try
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(@"..."))
        {
            conn.Open();

            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(@"select Name from Org", conn))
            {
                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        textBox1.Text = reader["Name"].ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
```

**Edit, Re Hierarchical table structures**

If you do need to retain separate iterators while navigating through multiple levels of a hierarchy, you will need multiple readers. As per @Philips answer, in order to have more than one active result set per `SqlConnection`, you'll need to [enable MARS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131686.aspx) (or open multiple connections).

```
try
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(@"...;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"))
    using (var cmdOuter = new SqlCommand(@"select distinct NodeLevel from Org", conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (var outerReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (outerReader.Read())
            {
                var nodeLevel = reader.GetInt32(0);
                Console.WriteLine("Node Level {0}", nodeLevel);
                using (var cmdInner = new SqlCommand(@"select Name from Org WHERE NodeLevel = @NodeLevel", conn))
                {
                    cmdInner.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NodeLevel", nodeLevel);
                    using (var innerReader = cmdInner.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (innerReader.Read())
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", innerReader.GetString(0));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: I am upvoting this because I think this answer best fits the OP. He propably does not really need multiple result sets.

Answer (score 2):

modify your connection string to allow multiple results :

```
connectionString="Data source=localhost; initial catalog=Interstone; integrated security=True; multipleactiveresultsets=True;"
```

scroll to the right for the right information ;-)

But there are lots of alternatives to avoid needing multiple queries at the same time. Each query you issue that is still pending is a resource that is being used at the server which should be minimized.

So first consider algorithms that don't require multiple cursors and if there is no alternative then setup mars.

Answer (score 0):

Reader is the wrong tool
And you do have an open reader

```
textBox1.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```